# How to use Mermaid style settings in NiceGUI

Tags: python-3.x, mermaid, nicegui

I am creating a flowchart with `mermaid` syntax in `nicegui`. I want to use the style settings `%%{ init : { "theme" : "default", "flowchart" : { "curve" : "linear" }}}%%%` but instead of a stylized image I get just text on the screen

```py
from nicegui import ui

ui.mermaid('''
%%{ init : { "theme" : "default", "flowchart" : { "curve" : "linear" }}}%%


flowchart LR
    f1 --> f2
    f2 --> f3
    f2 --> f4
''')

ui.run()
```

The main task is to make arrows with straight corners, not curved ones

Comment: Interesting! I wasn't aware of such inline configurations for Mermaid diagrams. But I don't see why they don't work with NiceGUI. Maybe we should create a feature request on GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/discussions/1861

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[We just found out](https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/discussions/1861) that these "directives" indicated with `%%` are deprecated, which might be a reason why the renderer breaks.

But the new configuration syntax works:

```py
ui.mermaid('''
---
config:
    theme: default
    flowchart:
        curve: linear
---

flowchart LR
    f1 --> f2
    f2 --> f3
    f2 --> f4
''')
```

[image]